# Asp.net mvc3 print web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on weyb application using **MVC3**. I want to print **MVC view** by using printer. Here my code.

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
        CustomerList custList = CreateCustomerList();
        string url = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"));
        custList.ImageUrl = url + "Content/report.jpg";
        return View("PrintDemo",custList);
 }
 private CustomerList CreateCustomerList()
 {
        return new CustomerList()
            {
                new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "Peter", Address = "St.Los", Place = "USA" },
                new Customer { Id = 2, Name = "Fred", Address = "Flink 9a", Place = "Rotterdam" },
                new Customer { Id = 3, Name = "Sjonnie", Address = "Paternatenplaats 44", Place = "Enkhuizen" },
                new Customer { Id = 4, Name = "Henk", Address = "Wakerdijk 74", Place = "Utrecht" },
                new Customer { Id = 5, Name = "Klaas", Address = "Paternatenplaats 44", Place = "Plaantan" },
                new Customer { Id = 6, Name = "Andre", Address = "Wolbrantskerkweg 90B ", Place = "Los Angeles" },
                new Customer { Id = 7, Name = "Pieter", Address = "Sam van Houtenstraat 191H", Place = "Emmen" },
                new Customer { Id = 8, Name = "Sjohn", Address = "Polostraat, M. 103-II", Place = "Kantens" },
                new Customer { Id = 9, Name = "John", Address = "Paternatenplaats 44", Place = "Leiden" },
                new Customer { Id = 10, Name = "Bruin", Address = "Anthony Spatzierhof 9", Place = "Maasbracht" },
                new Customer { Id = 11, Name = "Sjonnie", Address = "Van Heuven Goedhartlaan 201", Place = "Potters" },
                new Customer { Id = 12, Name = "Lumunon", Address = "Paternatenplaats 44", Place = "Utrecht" },
                new Customer { Id = 13, Name = "Friese", Address = "Burgemeester Roellstr 243-4", Place = "Rotterdam" },
                new Customer { Id = 14, Name = "Hudephol", Address = "Bilhamerstraat 4", Place = "Vlaardingen" },
                new Customer { Id = 15, Name = "Postema", Address = "Mastbos 77", Place = "Schiedam" },
                new Customer { Id = 16, Name = "Scharn", Address = "Marius Bauerstraat 123", Place = "Dordrecht" },
                new Customer { Id = 17, Name = "Wagenmakers", Address = "Pieter Postsingel 16", Place = "Ede" },
                new Customer { Id = 18, Name = "Gedikli", Address = "Burgemeester Hogguerstr 283", Place = "Twello" },
                new Customer { Id = 19, Name = "Zwollo", Address = "Meervalweg 140", Place = "Terschelling" },
                new Customer { Id = 20, Name = "Sjonnie", Address = "Ruys de Beerenbrouckstr 79A", Place = "Ter Aar" },
                new Customer { Id = 21, Name = "Schimmelmann", Address = "Ritzema Bosstraat 28-2", Place = "Vierenman" },
                new Customer { Id = 22, Name = "Makhlouf", Address = "Ln vd Helende Meesters 12", Place = "Eindhoven" },
                new Customer { Id = 23, Name = "Meyer", Address = "Burgemeester v Leeuwenln 79H", Place = "Breda" },
            };
}
```

Here is my **view**

```
@using MvcReportGeneratorDemo.Models
@model CustomerList

@{
<script type="text/javascript">
   function PrintDiv() {
       var divToPrint = document.getElementById('printarea');
       var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=auto,height=auto,location=no,left=200px');
       popupWin.document.open();
       popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');
       popupWin.document.close();
   }
</script>
}
<div id="printarea">
<br/>
<img src="@Model.ImageUrl" width="64" height="64" /> 
<br/>
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr border="1" bgcolor="#777777" color="#ffffff">
        <td width="20%" align="center">
            Name
        </td>
        <td width="50%" align="center">
            Address
        </td>
        <td width="30%" align="center">
            Place
        </td>
    </tr>
    @{
        var OddColor = "#DDEEEE";
        var evenColor = "#EEFFFF";
        var Odd = OddColor;
    }
    @foreach (Customer customer in Model)
    {
        <tr border="1" bgcolor="@Odd">
            <td>@customer.Name
            </td>
            <td>@customer.Address
            </td>
            <td>@customer.Place
            </td>
        </tr>
        if (Odd == OddColor)
        {
            Odd = evenColor;
        }
        else
        {
            Odd = OddColor;
        }
    }
</table>
```

When I run this code it shows me table in color format. Like follows
[image]

But when I print this it doesn't show rows in color. It doesn't show header in color. What can I do to show the color?

Comment: This is a browser/stylesheet/javascript type of question. It has nothing to do with ASP.NET or MVC. Does the window that you open show the colors? If it does, is your printer set to print with colors?

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC, but with HTML and CSS. Please show the relevant (a few rows is enough) HTML and CSS.

Comment: use a colour printer?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes windows shows color.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel What I did, I have downloaded pdf writer. When I click on print button I save it's pdf. PDF not shows color.

Comment: @Ajay My point was I doubt the fact colour is not displaying has anything to do with the code you have written, per se. When printing it will usually just print what you can see. I would check all external software settings / hardware.
The only other thing it may be is if you have a css for media=print set anywhere as this will be the stylesheet to use when printing.

Comment: You may want to look into setting a print style sheet.  Take a look [here](http://alistapart.com/article/goingtoprint) to get started.